# Get types of all instance variables in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class named Attributes, which has some instance variables as listed below:

```
public class Attributes {
   protected A variable1;
   protected B variable2;
   protected C variables3;
   
   /*
     Getters and Setters of each method.
  */
   
}
```

I want the list of all instance variables' types present in the class.

The output: `[A,B,C]`

This contains all possible dataTypes present in this class.

Can someone please suggest a way?

NOTE: I've seen reflection, but I think it is useful only if we have filled the values for these variables and we want to fetch the values and names of those variables, not the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can use the reflection method getType(). In order to get a list of all instance types it's as simple as:

```
Arrays.stream(Attributes.class.getDeclaredFields()).map(Field::getType).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Where the `getFields()` will return the array of all the fields within the class (and not its instances, you are referencing the class and not the instance of the class).
The `map()` part will map the field to its class type.
And the `collect(Collectors.toList())` will just get the stream result of Class<?> type to a List. If you don't want only the single class types, so no duplicates just use `toSet()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to access the `Field` and then get it's type:

See: [Field.getType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType--) && [Class.getDeclaredFields()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--)

Comment: To use reflection , we'll have to provide values to those instance variables , right ? 
I don't want to provide , i just want static list of all possible variabletypes present in the class/ interface .

Comment: The instance variables do not need values to work, they can be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reflection` to get the `type` like that:

```
class Scratch {

    public static class Test {
        private int a;
        private long b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = Test.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Type: " + fields[i].getType());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Type: int
Type: long
```